# Python requests return 403 when requests to groupon.com

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using requests to login groupon.com. But it returns 403 with this link: **https://www.groupon.com/signup?metric=layout_login&return_to=https://www.groupon.com**
This is my code:

```
a = requests.get('https://groupon.com')
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "Cookie": a.headers["Set-Cookie"],
    "Referer": "https://www.groupon.com/"
    }
requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Error 403: "The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated."      The groupon website also uses csrf token and you may have to use it  to authenticate.

Comment: The url you have mentioned in the code works fine, but the url you have mentioned earlier give 403 in browser, so that means it is a forbidden request, nothing to do with python, I guess.

Comment: Again, then I checked this feature of groupon, I guess this is not allowed in India, but when I changed my IP to a US one, it worked, so may be you need to change your IP while making request.

Comment: I request to "https://groupon.com/" worked. But with this link it didn't

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the behaviour of a specific website, rather than anything to do with Python or programming

Comment: If use POST request you will need _csrf hidden from https://www.groupon.com/signup?metric=layout_login&return_to=https://www.groupon.com

Comment: I think I will use selenium to do this. How to use many thread with selenium ?